# insert @NotNull annotation in POJO generated by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, annotations

I'm using Hiberate Tool plugin of eclipse juno to generate java beans mapping DB tables

It creates java files (for example):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIVITIES")
public class Activities implements java.io.Serializable {

    private ActivitiesId id;
    private String title;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "codiceCreatore", column = @Column(name = "codice_creatore", nullable = false)) 
    })
    public SynchActivitiesDTOId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(SynchActivitiesDTOId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitolo(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

I wolud like it writes @NotNull annotation too on attribute or get method:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIVITIES")
public class Activities implements java.io.Serializable {

    @NotNull
    private ActivitiesId id;
    @NotNull
    private String title;

    ...

}
```

I tried editing Ejb3PropertyGetAnnotation.ftl 
(in C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.hibernate.eclipse.libs_3.4.0.v20120611-2017-H93-Final\lib\tools\hibernate-tools.jar\pojo)
adding

```
<#if !property.optional>
    @${pojo.importType("org.hibernate.validator.NotNull")}
</#if>
```

but there are no changes in Activities.java

How I have to do?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I tried to modify 
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.hibernate.eclipse.libs_3.4.0.v20120611-2017-H93-Final\lib\tools\hibernate-tools.jar\pojo\PojoFields

```
<#foreach field in pojo.getAllPropertiesIterator()><#if pojo.getMetaAttribAsBool(field, "gen-property", true)> <#if pojo.hasMetaAttribute(field, "field-description")>    /**
     ${pojo.getFieldJavaDoc(field, 0)}
     */
 </#if>    ${pojo.getFieldModifiers(field)} ${pojo.getJavaTypeName(field, jdk5)} ${field.name}<#if pojo.hasFieldInitializor(field, jdk5)> = ${pojo.getFieldInitialization(field, jdk5)}</#if>;
</#if>
+ <#if !field.optional>@${pojo.importType("org.hibernate.validator.NotNull")}</#if>
</#foreach>
```

but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a tweak approach (very practical) via hibernate reverse engineering xml.
Eclipse hibernate tools will let you specify one.

For your table for example include the following meta attibute for column named id:

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table-filter package="my.package" match-name="ACTIVITIES" />
    <table name="ACTIVITIES">
        <meta attribute="extra-import">javax.validation.constraints.NotNull</meta>
        <column name="titolo">
            <meta attribute="scope-field">@NotNull private</meta>
        </column>
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

The field will be scoped with qualifier we give for "scope-field" attribute. There we tweak in whatever extra qualifiers we need. In this example, we mark it private along with additionally adding in @NotNull qualifier. See the meta attribue used above for extra import as well.

For a full listing of meta attributes - see this [link](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/4.0/html/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/codegen.html)

HTH.

Comment: Thaks for your answer. I have a lot of table and it's too much expansive to edit "reveng.xml" for all tables and all columns.

Comment: So i'm looking for a way to generate @NotNull annotation on all my entities.

Comment: why not try a wild card in the name (ie, *)

Comment: i'm using this reveng.xml:

Comment: using 
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <type-mapping>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="VARCHAR" hibernate-type="string">
        </sql-type>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="NVARCHAR" hibernate-type="string">
        </sql-type>
    </type-mapping>
    
    <table name="ACTIVITIES">
     <meta attribute="extra-import"> javax.validation.constraints.NotNull</meta>
     <column name="titolo">
     <meta attribute="scope-field">@NotNull private</meta>
     </column>
 </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
i cannot get @NotNull annotiation in my generated classes

Comment: You seem to have missed the table filter.

Comment: for example:  <table-filter package="my.package" match-name="ACTIVITIES" />